# jQuery Selector - checked and class begins with

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector, checked

I need to get the value of the first checkbox which is checked and who's class name begins with 'rqc', eg. rqc205

I have tried this: `requestID=$('#requestsTable').find('input[class^='rqc']:checked').val();`

but it yields nothing, whereas `requestID=$('#requestsTable').find('input:checked').val();` works but does not limit to the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Either fix your quotes around the attribute value, or remove them altogether (they don't seem to be required).

```
requestID = $('#requestsTable').find("input[class^='rqc']:checked").val();
```

or

```
requestID = $('#requestsTable').find("input[class^=rqc]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
requestID = $('#requestsTable').find('input[class^="rqc"]').filter(':checked').val();
```

This is, currently un-checked/un-verified. I think it *should* work, but I'm still new to jQuery, so I'll post the possibility, check it and then amend if necessary.

---

Much to my surprise, that works.

But it's worth pointing out, I think, that it might be easier to get the value using jQuery's `click()` event.

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('input[class^="rqc"]').click(
            function() {
                var requestID = $(this).val();
            }
        );

    }
);
```

Though obviously that depends on what exactly you're doing, and why.